# Null pointer exception in action bar

Tags: android, null, android-actionbar

good morning every one,

I am using swipe tabs in fragments but getting null action bar.

Code snippet is given below:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.ride_detail, container, false);
        li = getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState);
        context = getActivity();
        customizedToast = new CustomizedToast(context, li);
         actionBar = ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getActionBar();
```

I have also tried with:

```
 actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
```

Thanks.

Comment: try it, actionBar = getActionBar();

Comment: @Soham he should use an AppCompatActivity (not an Activity)

Comment: getSupportActionBar()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `getSupportActionBar` instead of `getActionBar` if you are working with `ActionBarActivity`. The getActionBar method is available in the ActionBarActivity API since it extends Activity, but should not be used when working with support Activities.

Check you import which action bar you are importing...

Comment: Thanks for providing help

Comment: Use AppCompatActivity instead of ActionBarActivity. It is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Change `Activity` theme in Android Manifest to `Theme.Holo`

Comment: Why should he use a Holo theme in 2015?

Comment: You can use Themes like Holo which support Actionbar